# Dividing by the Grand Total

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to determine a weighted percentage where I divide a measure by the grand total of another measure (that will not be affected by filtering).  The below formula doesn't work.

```
Weight = ABS(SUM([Delta Qty (CSL2)])) / 
         CALCULATE(SUM(ALL('CSL2',('CSL2'[Target Qty [sales unit]]))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a variable instead of doing it directly:

```
Weight = 
VAR Base1 = CALCULATE(SUM('CSL2'[Target Qty sales unit]),ALL('CSL2'))
RETURN ABS(SUM([Delta Qty CSL2]))/Base1
```

Hope this helps.